# Delphi: Socket.ReadBytes(); vs IOHandler.ReadBytes()

Tags: delphi, sockets, indy

Whats the difference between:

```
AContext.Socket.ReadBytes(...);

 vs

AContext.IOHandler.ReadBytes(...);
```

Do they work the same ? Or maybe some cache in IOHandler or something?

Comment: using IdTCPClient , Delphi 2010, Indy 10

Comment: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/510978.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are actually the exact same method. The `Socket` property points to the same `IOHandler` component when it is a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived object (which is most of the time), and is `nil` otherwise. You should use the `IOHandler` property directly for most I/O operations, as it offers more flexibility to use Indy with different types of I/O systems. The `Socket` property is a useful shortcut for socket-specific functionality, like accessing the socket's associated IP/Port values.